# why no match oprator in dev c++ ide in vector taking input by user

Tags: c++, loops, vector, input

```
vector <int> v[6];
     for(int i=0; i<v.size(); i++){
        cin>>v[i];
     }
```

I tried to change operator but it's not working.

Comment: `vector <int> v[6]` defines `v` as an array of `vector<int>` but since there is no overloaded `operator>>` for `vector<int>` we get the mentioned error.

Comment: In modern C++ its better to use "range for" instead of C-style for when iterating over containers (and in some other cases). So, use `for (int& i : v) { cin >> i; }` and in your case you will see compiler complaining right away that it can't asssign `std::vector<int>&` to `int&`.

Comment: `[]` is used to declare arrays, you are trying to declare a vector with a given size. So you want to pass that size to the appropriate vector constructor. Use `()` for that `vector<int> v(6);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vector <int> v[6]` defines `v` as an array of `vector<int>` thus `v[i]` gives us a `vector<int>` but since there is no overloaded `operator>>` for `vector<int>` we get the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

You actually declared a 2-d structure by using both `vector` and `[]` together.

Either use `vector<int> v(6)` or `int v[6]` for a 1-d data structure.